# JQuery - generating a grid from a list of words

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently this script takes the words from the list and generates a grid, giving the words random positions each time. When the words are generated I want them to be split into individual characters, into cells next to each other so the word still makes sense - how do I do this?

```
  var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", ];
 var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0, 12);
 shuffledWords.sort(function () {
     return 0.5 - Math.random();
 });

 var table = $('<table class="tablestyle">');
 var rows = 6;
 var cols = 2;
 var tr;
 var index;

 for (var row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
     tr = $('<tr>');
     for (var col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
         index = (row * cols) + col;
         $('<td>').text(shuffledWords[index]).appendTo(tr);
     }
     tr.appendTo(table);
 }

 table.appendTo('body');

 $('<table>' + innerTable + '</table>').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I right to assume that for each word you want a new row, and for letter in the word you want a new cell?

Try this:

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", ];
 var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0, 12);
 shuffledWords.sort(function () {
     return 0.5 - Math.random();
 });

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.style.border='solid 1px silver';

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i++)
{
    var word = shuffledWords[i];
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    for (var j = 0; j < word.length; j++)
    {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.style.border='solid 1px silver';

        cell.innerText = word[j];
        // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }

    tbl.appendChild(row);    
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YJjkB/1/

Comment: I though that's what I provided. Can you provide an expected html output?

Comment: The intro line may have been misleading. I've corrected this. Is it what you require?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working and there is no output in jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry! It works in Chrome and IE. FF doesn't like 'innerText'. Use 'textContent' in FF instead. (See comment in code).

Comment: Ahh thanks mate all sorted. I already have the CSS to style it but how do I link that up? thanks

Comment: Add "tbl.className = 'tablestyle';" and remove the ".style.border...;" lines.

Comment: what about if I wanted some more columns

Comment: but i want a 6x6 how would i do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13859/discussion-between-flem-and-m0onio)